how to stop a thread? Is it possible to tie a thread to a global variable? the thread2 in this script is not visible to elife statment event
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from my_scripts import *
from my_constants import *
import sys
import glob
import yt_dlp
import threading
import time

global thread2

sg.LOOK_AND_FEEL_TABLE['MyCreatedTheme'] = {'BACKGROUND': '#000066', 
                                        'TEXT': '#ffebbf', 
                                        'INPUT': '#354230', 
                                        'TEXT_INPUT': '#ffebbf', 
                                        'SCROLL': '#99CC99', 
                                        'BUTTON': ('#003333', '#FFCC66'), 
                                        'PROGRESS': ('#D1826B', '#CC8019'), 
                                        'BORDER': 1, 'SLIDER_DEPTH': 0, 'PROGRESS_DEPTH': 0, } 

# Switch to use your newly created theme 
sg.theme('MyCreatedTheme') 

sg.theme_background_color('#4eae61')
sg.set_options(font=('Fira Code', 16), background_color= '#555f9a')
l1 = sg.Text('Put url here',font=('Fira Code', 16), expand_x=True, justification='center')
t1 = sg.Text('', enable_events=True, font=('Fira Code', 16), justification='left')
t2 = sg.InputText( font=('Fira Code', 16),  justification='left', default_text='5', key='-folder-')

def delete_video_in_D():
        list_of_files = [os.remove(p)  for p in glob.glob(r'D:\\*.*') if (os.path.isfile(p) and is_video(p))]
        

layout = [
    [l1],
    [t1,  sg.InputText(key='-url-')], 
    [t2],
    [sg.Button('Download',  button_color='#b1defb')],
    [sg.Button('Cancel playing',  button_color='#fbceb1')],
    ]


FOLDERS = {'1':Chef_Max_Mariola_PATH,
           '2':JuliaCrossBow_PATH,
           '3':French_Vibes_PATH,
           '4':Studio_Italiano_InClasse_PATH,
           '5':'D:\\'}


window = sg.Window('Main Window', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Download':
        delete_video_in_D()
        url = values['-url-']
        folder = values['-folder-']
        os.chdir(FOLDERS[folder])
        try:
            with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
                thread1 = threading.Thread(target=ydl.download, args=(url, ), daemon=True)
                thread1.start()
                while True:
                    if thread1.is_alive():
                        pass
                    else:
                        list_of_files = [x for x in glob.glob(r'*.*') if os.path.isfile(x) and is_video(x)]
                        latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
                        new_name = re.sub(r'\s*\[.*?\]\s*', '', latest_file )
                        os.rename(latest_file, new_name)
                        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=play_video, args=(new_name,), daemon=True).start()
                        break         
            
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(e).__name__, e)

    elif event == 'Cancel playing': # thread2 is not visible here
        thread2.stop()
# the error message I get when click on button 'Cancel playing' is
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'       
window.close()


What do you mean with "not visible"? What happens, what should happen? If there are error messages, show them completely as properly formatted text in the question.

@MichaelButscher, you are right. I have updated my post. The error I get is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'

The method start of a thread returns None. Therefore handle thread creation and start in different steps as you did it for thread1.

@MichaelButscher. Thank you. Now that I used handle creation and start in different steps, the thread2 is not None. Stopping the tread I have to learn. There is no thread method called stop()

Most of time, I do it by using a flag, or a global variable,  to stop the while loop in my sub-thread.
A simple, short and executable example Code may help people to help.
import time
import datetime
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def job(window):
    global running
    while running:
        window.write_event_value('Event', datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(0.1)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("00:00:00", font=("Courier New", 20, "bold"), justification='center', expand_x=True, key="TIME")],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Start'), sg.Button('Stop')],
]
window = sg.Window('Threading', layout)
running, old = False, None

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        running = False
        time.sleep(0.5)
        break

    elif event == 'Start' and not running:
        running = True
        window['Start'].update(disabled=True)
        threading.Thread(target=job, args=(window, ), daemon=True).start()

    elif event == 'Stop':
        running = False
        window['Start'].update(disabled=False)

    elif event == 'Event':
        now = values[event]
        if now != old:
            window["TIME"].update(now)
            old = now

window.close()


Here's a version of Jason's code with a few changes that may/may not be instructional.

Used the PySimpleGUI threading API to start the thread

One less import
Automatically provides an event when the thread exits


Instead of global variable, used the shared window object to store "job running flag". This could enable multiple windows to use the same thread code.
When closing window with X waits for the thread to exit

‍♂️  Jason did all the work here.... I just modified his work.
import time
import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def job(window):
    while window.job_running:
        window.write_event_value('Event', datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(0.1)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("00:00:00", font=("Courier New", 20, "bold"), justification='center', expand_x=True, key="TIME")],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Start'), sg.Button('Stop')]]

window = sg.Window('Threading', layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True)

window.job_running = False
exiting = False

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        if window.job_running:                  # if thread running, tell it to exit
            window.job_running = False
            exiting = True
        else:
            break                               # if thread not running then OK to exit
            
    if exiting and event == '-THREAD ENDED-':   # If exiting and thread is finished then OK to exit
        break

    elif event == 'Start':
        window['Start'].update(disabled=True)
        window.job_running = True
        window.start_thread(lambda: job(window), '-THREAD ENDED-')

    elif event == 'Stop':
        window.job_running = False
        window['Start'].update(disabled=False)

    elif event == 'Event' and values[event] != window["TIME"].get():
        window["TIME"].update(values[event])

window.close()


